# replace search condition with table alias rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an SQL query as follows:

```
    SELECT * FROM results 
                WHERE (f_player1='O´Shea, John' OR f_player2='O´Shea, John')
```

I want to dynamically replace `'O´Shea, John'` with a group by other players based on a whether they have played.

```
SELECT player FROM
(
    SELECT f_player1 AS player FROM results WHERE DATE(f_datetime) = CURDATE()
    UNION 
    SELECT f_player2 AS player FROM results WHERE DATE(f_datetime) = CURDATE()
) x
```

This gives me a list of 5 rows (of players). How can I dynamically incorporate all 5 of those players to replace the original string?

Is it through a join?, temporary variable?

Comment: `WHERE (f_player1='O´Shea, John' OR f_player2='O´Shea, John')` is equal to `WHERE 'O´Shea, John' IN (f_player1, f_player2)`.

Comment: `O´Shea`? What is `´`>

Comment: What *exactly* do you mean be *dynamically incorporate all 5 of those players to replace the original string*. Please provide sample data and expected results. Ideally, create an [mcve] on somewhere like https://dbfiddle.uk and post the link in your question.

Answer (score 1):

A join would look thus:

```
SELECT r.*
FROM results r
JOIN
(
  SELECT f_player1 AS player FROM results WHERE DATE(f_datetime) = CURDATE()
  UNION 
  SELECT f_player2 AS player FROM results WHERE DATE(f_datetime) = CURDATE()
) p ON p.player IN (r.f_player1, r.f_player2);
```

This gives you all results for all players who played today.

I'd suggest an `EXISTS` clause here, though, because you want to select rows when certain rows *exist*.

```
SELECT r.*
FROM results r
WHERE EXISTS
(
  SELECT NULL
  FROM results r2
  WHERE DATE(r2.f_datetime) = CURDATE()
  AND 
  (
    r2.f_player1 IN (r.f_player1, r.f_player2) 
     OR
    r2.f_player2 IN (r.f_player1, r.f_player2)
  )
);
```